# Swift - How can I add an event listener for cancelling an email dialog?

Tags: swift, xcode6

I'm using text attribute to detect an email. It's working fine but what I need is a listener if the user did cancel sending email or not.
How can I achieve that with Xcode?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Can you please elaborate.

Comment: We can help you but we need more explaination of your need :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to provide more information , photos of your problem.
And possible a sample code.
If you can detect a result of the email being added properly then you should handle the nil.
You didn't specify if the cancel option is a button or an .addAction method. In both cases you can use a Notification / Observers.

```
class StepCounter {
var totalSteps: Int = 0 {
    willSet(newTotalSteps) {
        println("About to set totalSteps to \(newTotalSteps)")
    }
    didSet {
        if totalSteps > oldValue  {
            println("Added \(totalSteps - oldValue) steps")
        }
    }
}
```

}